# why is the .htaccess auth command not working in a directory in Drupal 9

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd, ddev

i have a mini website below my sites default files directory and i am trying to make it be password protected with the following .htaccess file which i put in that same directory:

```
#Protect Directory
AuthName "Dialog prompt"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /Users/dianacastillo/Projects/dam/web/sites/default/files/microsites/food-lineup/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

I also created an .htpasswd file in the same directory.

however when i browse to this directory from the site, it does not ask for any authentication. what could be wrong?

Comment: Are you simply serving static files from this directory? Are `.htaccess` overrides enabled for this subdirectory? Add any nonsense to the file, do you get an error?

Comment: i'm in ddev and i put this file in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf <Directory "/var/www/html/sites/default/files/microsites">
  AllowOverride AuthConfig
  # The Options below is an example. Use what you deem is necessary.
  Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>

Comment: i figured it out see my answer below. thanks

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Glad you got it working, although that `<Directory>` container isn't necessarily correct... it appears to cover a different directory than the one stated in the question? `MultiViews` and `Indexes` should probably be disabled (not enabled) and the `Order` and `Allow` directives are Apache 2.2 directives (I would assume you are on 2.4?) and could conflict with the `Require` directive in `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this didnt work because i was using ddev .  ddev uses nginx, not apache ,  i switched to apache in the conf.yaml for ddev and now it works.